# JS script function not working in php

Tags: javascript, php, function

Here is my JS function:

```
function checkError() {
            var field = 'error';
            var url = window.location.href;
            document.write('test');
            window.alert('please work');
            if(url.indexOf('?' + field + '=') != -1)
                document.write('The username and password do not match. Do not use your full email.');
return true;            
            }
```

and then in my body paragraph I have:

```
<?php echo '<script> checkError();</script>' ?>
```

It doesn't have any errors calling it. But the function does nothing on my page. Any thoughts? I've tried putting the JS script in the page and in a JS file and correctly called for its inclusion.

Full script:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Secure Login</title>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/functions.js"></script>

        <link href="stylesheets/mainStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="stylesheets/formStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <?php include('header.php'); ?>

        <div id="mainContent">
          <h1>Member Login</h1>
          <div id="mainParaText">
          <?php echo '<script> checkError();</script>' ?>
        </div>

     </body>
</html>
```

TURNS OUT JS Function is UNDEFINED. Ugh, can't figure out why (thought I fixed this problem a while back lol)

Comment: Show full usage of this script. Any errors in console?

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the Net tab. Is the request for the script being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: Is that the only function in the JS file? You don't seem to have included all of it (but I would expect to see more errors in the console showing that).

Answer (score 0):

> try like this:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Secure Login</title>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/functions.js"></script>

    <link href="stylesheets/mainStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="stylesheets/formStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkError(){
           var field = 'error';
        var url = window.location.href;
        document.write('test');
        window.alert('please work');
        if(url.indexOf('?' + field + '=') != -1)
            document.write('The username and password do not match. Do not use your full email.');
        return true;   
        }

       <?php
           echo "checkError();";
       ?>
   </script>
</head>

 <body>

      <?php include('header.php'); ?>

     <div id="mainContent">
      <h1>Member Login</h1>
      <div id="mainParaText">
      <?php echo '<script> checkError();</script>' ?>
    </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

JS is client side and PHP is server side.

That means that everything in PHP code will be processed on server and then "echoed" to your browser where you get undefined error.

When debugging this you should always check source code in the browser first so you see exactly what your server echoed.

I'm guessing a bit but try with double quotes instead of single.

And not related to the question ...
You are checking username and password with JS? How exactly will you do this? With ajax call back to the server? If you check with JS that means password should be in the source code somewhere and that is NOT secure. Username / pass validation should always be made on serverside (either with ajax request or usual submit form).

Comment: "I'm guessing a bit but try with double quotes instead of single." — What possible difference could that make given the code we can see?

Comment: if you look at the function, i'm checking for a query statement in the url which if there is an error, I redirect the user to the login page with the error query